# Product images are uploaded in admin panel but cant be seen in the front view

Tags: magento-1.8, product-images, ce-1.8.1.0, file-permissions

I have magento 1.8.1.0, when adding products the images are uploaded in the admin panel but can't be seen in front view of shop. Have checked the images are stored in `media/catalog/product/` folder. Have refreshed the cache and checked, removed the `.htaccess` file in media folder, checked folder permission is set to 777. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to reindex. Because magento follows EAV structure to save data in database.
Also check whether images are shown in admin panel by right clicking and open image in new tab option?

Comment: Yes, i have done reindexing, still no images and I right click on image and i'm able to view them

Comment: You said that the folder permission is right. Did you check the file permission as well? It should be 644...

Comment: so media,catalog,product... all these folders need to have 777 permission and image file 644?

Comment: did change the file permissions to 644, still no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be the theme's issue, when i switched the store view to default theme, I was able to see the product images. I have contacted the theme author for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check 1) Make sure that you have selected one of the image as Base, thumbnail and small image, in the Backend under Images.

[image]

Check 2) If still issue, try in your catalog/product/view.phtml

```
var_dump($this->getProduct());
```

and see if you are getting image urls in the dump?

Comment: yes i have selected as shown but still no product images

Comment: try the check 2 in the edit and try to debug the issue

Comment: I got this when did the check 2 step -  ["image"]=> string(21) "/a/t/aten-kn2140v.jpg" ["small_image"]=> string(21) "/a/t/aten-kn2140v.jpg" ["thumbnail"]=> string(21) "/a/t/aten-kn2140v.jpg" ["url_key"]=> string(68) "aten-kn2140v-40-port-kvm-over-ip-switch-1-local-2-remote-user-access" ["url_path"]=> string(73) "aten-kn2140v-40-port-kvm-over-ip-switch-1-local-2-remote-user-access.html"

Comment: do you see your image files in that path? they should be in that path under media/catalog/product folder

Comment: yes they are present in media/catalog/product/a/t/aten-kn2140v.jpg

Comment: You should Clear your cache from backend, System > Cache Management , also make sure Compiler is disabled.
System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button

Comment: Cleared the cache and compiler is already disabled

Answer (score 0):

I increased the php_value `memory_limit` in `.htaccess` file to `512M`, and currently i'm able to see images in category view page but see placeholder images on product view.